CrewAI not finding co-worker
I'm new to python and its frameworks, but I'm an experienced C# developer. I'm attempting to write a test "Crew" for CrewAI, but I'm getting:
Error executing tool. Co-worker mentioned not found, it must to be one of the following options:
- writer

A single-agent crew works as I would expect, but adding the second agent (writer) causes this failure. A few times it even led to asking me how to communicate with "writer," and it's generating that text from my local LLM as I would expect.
Changing to Process.hierarchical and adding the appropriate manager_llm results in a "Crew Manager" that can't talk to either agent. In Process.sequential, once the "researcher" limits out on attempts and returns a result, "writer" begins. None of the agents can talk to each other. From my understanding this is all built on langchain, which I know basically nothing about. I don't know where to even begin troubleshooting this.
Here's my entire code sample, largely derived from a direct sample in the CrewAI docs:
from crewai import Agent, Task, Crew, Process
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.agents import tool


@tool
def get_client_feedback(query: str):
    """Pass a question defined in the 'query' variable to the human to get more details."""
    return input("\n\n"+query)

# Creating a senior researcher agent with memory and verbose mode
researcher = Agent(
    role='Senior Researcher',
    goal='Uncover groundbreaking technologies',
    verbose=True,
    backstory=(
        "Driven by curiosity, you're at the forefront of technological"
        "innovation, eager to explore and share knowledge that could change"
        "the world."
    ),
    llm=ChatOpenAI(
        model="crewai-llama3-latest",
        base_url="http://localhost:11434/v1",
        api_key="NA"
    ),
    tools=[get_client_feedback],
    allow_delegation=True
)

# Creating a writer agent with custom tools and delegation capability
writer = Agent(
    role='Writer',
    goal='Narrate compelling tech stories about technology',
    verbose=True,
    backstory=(
        "With a flair for simplifying complex topics, you craft"
        "engaging narratives that captivate and educate, bringing new"
        "discoveries to light in an accessible manner."
    ),
    llm=ChatOpenAI(
        model="crewai-llama3-latest",
        base_url="http://localhost:11434/v1",
        api_key="NA"
    ),
    tools=[get_client_feedback],
    allow_delegation=False
)

# Research task
research_task = Task(
    description=(
        "Identify the next big trend in technology."
        "Focus on identifying pros and cons and the overall narrative."
        "Your final report should clearly articulate the key points,"
        "its market opportunities, and potential risks."
    ),
    expected_output='A comprehensive 3 paragraphs long report on the latest AI trends.',
    tools=[get_client_feedback],
    agent=researcher,
)

# Writing task with language model configuration
write_task = Task(
    description=(
        "Compose an insightful article on technology."
        "Focus on the latest trends and how it's impacting the industry."
        "This article should be easy to understand, engaging, and positive."
    ),
    expected_output='A 4 paragraph article on technological advancements formatted as markdown.',
    agent=writer,
    async_execution=False,
    output_file='new-blog-post.md'  # Example of output customization
)

# Forming the tech-focused crew with some enhanced configurations
crew = Crew(
  agents=[researcher, writer],
  tasks=[research_task, write_task],
  process=Process.sequential,  # Optional: Sequential task execution is default
  share_crew=True,
  verbose=2
)

# Starting the task execution process with enhanced feedback
result = crew.kickoff()
print(result)


I think it is because of the delegation that you have in the researcher. Mark it false and give it a whirl.

There is a bug in some older versions of CrewAI that caused a similar problem when using delegation with custom tools, but that didn't fix this. In fact, I rolled back to an older version of CrewAI, and this part of it started working (it just broke other things). So, it may just be a bug in CrewAI.

@NathanWheeler which version did you roll back to?

Having the same problem with version 0.51.1  (current at present time).

It is also happening when allow_delegation=False
